# Why doesn't my Eclipse start in El Capitan?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have been working in Eclipse for a while and recently I had to change java_home for some other application. Since then my Eclipse doesn't start. I have followed all the solutions posted to questions similar to this but no use. These are some details regarding the problem.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 1.8.0_92
```

When I try to open Eclipse through terminal via open Eclipse.app/ , I get prompt to look at the following log at /Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/1465758949259.log

```
!SESSION 2016-06-12 12:15:49.142 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.8.0_92
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -    keyring /Users/***/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -keyring /Users/***/.eclipse_keyring    -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-12 12:15:50.124
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationWillFinishLaunching(Display.java:5244)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5344)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.finishLaunching(Display.java:5025)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5321)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.finishLaunching(NSApplication.java:59)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.init(Display.java:2221)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:131)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:721)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:712)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:790)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:169)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:111)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

config.ini

```
#This configuration file was written by: 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Thu Feb 18 03:26:43 EST 2016
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.cpp
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/Documents/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.102.v20160118-1700.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.100.v20150423-1455.jar@1\:start
   org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.100.v20150402-1551.jar
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
```

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

In the previous questions, many have suggested to remove few files in the .metadata folder in workspace. I have tried completely removing the workspace itself but still Eclipse won't start. I have also tried ./eclipse -clean. Any guide would be really helpful.

Comment: Looking at the source there appears to be a problem with the `NSBundle.bundleWithIdentifier(NSString.stringWith("com.apple.JavaVM"))` call. So I guess some sort of issue with finding the Java VM.

Comment: Post the contents of your `config.ini` ...

Comment: What's with the odd amount of space after the `-` in `-    keyring`?

Comment: @user1429322: Which files specifically in `.metadata` did you remove?

Comment: @I'L'I I removed the whole workspace

Comment: If you `cd .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources` do you see anything in there (eg. `.snap`)? Also try removing or commenting out `-vmargs` in `eclipse.ini`

Comment: I dont have .metadata folder as I have removed the whole workspace folder including this folder. Also removing -vmargs doesn't help

Comment: Okay, one more thing to try in `eclipse.ini` change `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7` to `1.8`

Comment: It gives the same error. As @greg mentioned, could this be because of JavaVM? Where should be it located or set?

Comment: Yes, it very well could be, and also there's the concern which nitind mentioned, with the spacing in your constants and arguments. That doesn't look correct, although I'm not sure if that would have the effect on it that you seem to have.

Comment: When you run `./eclipse -clean` you should also add `-clearPersistedState`